# Python beautifulsoup select CSS issue

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Learning scrapy and I'm trying to use it to get some specific topics in a forum.

In the forum the infomation I need is stored like:

```
<tbody id="threadnumber">
<tr>
<th class="new">
<em>[<a href="topicID">topic</a>]</em> 
<a href="thread*****.html" onclick="atarget(this)"   class="post">postname</a>
</th>
<td class="by">
<a something to show the poster and time>**</a>
</td>
<td class="num">
<a something to show the numbers of read and replys>**</a>
</td>
<td class="by">
<a something to show the last replyer and time>**</a>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>

<tbody id="threadnumber">#next thread
<tr>....
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Is there any method to get the postname in the second a tag for a specific topic whose unique topicid is stored in the first a tag. Should I use sibling?

For example I get

*[NEWS]* 
    news1

*[NEWS]* 
    news2

*[NEWS]* 
    news3

*[PIC]* 
    picture1

for input.

And I want to get an output only include "NEWS" topic like['news1','news2','news3']

Thanks for your help!

Comment: post sample input and expected output with your question.

Comment: I add some simplified sample, is it clear?

Comment: Are both the topic and the postname included in one upper level tag (`<li>`, `<p>` or...)?

Comment: And... what is the rule (even in plain English) to identify a topic and the associated postname?

Comment: Yes, I think they are both included in a <th> tag

Comment: You really should post a part of the html containing at least 2 successive postnames, with the enclosing tags...

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to contact a post with its topic.Respectively I use soup.select('a[href="***"]') or soup.select('a[calss="***"]') to identify topic and postname. @SergeBallesta

Comment: I try to improve it, is the html part sufficient now?@SergeBallesta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use BeautifulSoup to find all tags with `class="post"`. Then for each tag, you search a `<a>` tag in a descendant from its parent, and test whether its text is the topic you are interested in. If true, you add the postname to a result list. Code could be:

```
def findposts(soup, topic):
'''Finds all postname associated to topic in a BeautifulSoup element'''
    posts = []              # initialize an empty result list
    # search postnames by class
    for postname in soup.findAll('a', attrs = {'class': 'post'}):
        # find associated topic in immediate parent
        if postname.findParent().find('a').text == topic:
            posts.append(postname.text)    # Ok add to result list
    return posts
```

With your example data, you could do:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup('data', 'html.parser')
print(findpost(soup, 'topic')
```

and the result would be as expected:

```
['postname']
```